# Android Dynamic Color Substitution

Tags: android, colors, themes, android-resources

Android colors can be stored as a resource. Examples:

- `@android:color/white`
- `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>`

Is it possible to intercept Android's attempt to resolve a color resource reference (e.g. `@android:color/white` and `@color/white`), and force it to resolve to any arbitrary color we like during run-time?  Ideally, the interception process would be able to detect what the color specification relates to (visual Android widget; specific theme; etc.), but just being able to dynamically replace colors should be sufficient.

Comment: You can't reliably override resource loading, and in general you should never try to subclass `Resources`. That said, there are lots of ways to dynamically colors things but the best approach will depend on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: How would you dynamically replace the color used for android:colorPrimary?

For example, you have deployed a generic Android application into the Google Store and then need to skin the experience depending upon the organization that the end-user belongs to.

Comment: The primary color is only used to style the action bar, so you could just set your action bar's background from code. Likewise, the primary dark color is only used to style the status bar, so you could just set the status bar color from code.

Comment: Understood.  Setting the action-bar's background colour was always an option, irrespective of it having its background being set to colorPrimary as a default.  I wanted to use pseudo colours that are resolved at runtime.  This would have provided a nicer separation of concerns, and reduce the amount of coding required to skin the application.  Oh well, thank you very much for verifying my research on the topic.

Comment: P.S.: What are your thoughts on NativeCSS (NativeCSS.com)?